# Angular 2 - change videos src after clicking on div

Tags: html, angular

I have problem with video src. After clicking on my div (camera) in source code I can see that video src is changing properly, but videos arent being played. What should I do?

Below are my components - streaming.component.ts (responsible for displaying videos of chosen camera component) and camera.component.ts (for viewing icon with camera name)

**streaming.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CameraComponent} from '../camera/camera.component';

@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'streaming',
   template: `
            <camera cameraName="Kamera 1" (click)='cameraStream("sample.mp4")'></camera>
            <camera cameraName="Kamera 2" (click)='cameraStream("sample2.mp4")'></camera>
            <camera cameraName="Kamera 3" (click)='cameraStream("sample3.mp4")'></camera>
            <camera cameraName="Kamera 4" (click)='cameraStream("sample4.mp4")'></camera>
            <video width="800" controls>
                <source src = "{{cameraSrc}}" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
            </video>
            <p>{{cameraSrc}}</p>
            `,
directives: [CameraComponent]
})
export class StreamingComponent {

 cameraSrc:string;
 constructor() { }

 cameraStream(chosenCamera :string){
    this.cameraSrc=chosenCamera;
  }
 }
```

Videos are working ,because when I put

```
<source src = "{{cameraSrc}}" type="video/mp4">
```

everything is fine.

**camera.component.ts**

```
import { Component ,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'camera',
    templateUrl: 'camera.component.html'
})
export class CameraComponent {
     @Input() cameraName:string = "";

     constructor() { }

 }
```

[Here is what I get after clicking on camera2 for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18fbl.jpg)
.

Comment: Have you tried `<source [src]="cameraSrc" type="video/mp4">` ?

Comment: It's not working :(

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Don't know why, but that way:

```
<video width="800" [src] = "cameraSrc" controls>
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

It is working.

Comment: You should really take a look at the Tour of Heroes, an official intro-tutorial for Angular 2 on their official website. Also, "don't know why but it works" is not really an answer, let alone should be the accepted answer.

Comment: So explain me, why that way:
<source [src]="cameraSrc" type="video/mp4">

it is not working?

Comment: I can not explain why the solution with the source tag does not work, but your solution indeed _should_ work. The video tag does have an optional src attribute. see: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. This seems to be a bug in Angular, imo.

Comment: Thank you!!! I've been struggling with this for awhile and this one worked! Adding the src to the <source> tag didn't work for me either.

Comment: I think it's because the video tag itself needs to be rebuilt and not just the source element inside it. If you move [src] to the video tag then angular will detect that the full video element needs to be rebuilt when the [src] value changes.

Comment: Thanks its working. But below answer by @Javarome 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50914423/7562674 seems perfect and working. In my case  blob created in service subscribe and it needs to be reloaded and then started working.

Answer (score 16):

Changing `src` is not enough for `<video>`, you need to reload it:

```
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) { }   // To find elements inside component

cameraStream(chosenCamera: string) {
  this.cameraSrc = chosenCamera;
  const player = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('video');
  player.load();
}
```

Or more generally, you can make your component watch the changes through the `OnChanges` contract:

```
cameraStream(chosenCamera: string) {
  this.cameraSrc = chosenCamera;
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  if (changes.cameraSrc) {
    const player = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('video');
    player.load();
  }
}
```

(Of course you don't need to lookup the `player` element every time if you can secure its unchanging value before, like in `ngOnInit`)

Comment: Thank you very much, i was wondering for 2 hours why the change did not effect the audio player... We have to reload it....

Answer (score 11):

In html template use video tag

```
<video #video id="video" width="100%" height="100%" controls></video>

<mat-icon (click)="playVideo(url)">
            play_arrow
          </mat-icon>
```

In Component

```
@ViewChild('video')

public video: ElementRef;

playVideo(url: string) {
    this.video.nativeElement.src = url;
    this.video.nativeElement.load();
    this.video.nativeElement.play();
  }
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. I believe it's the template ref `#video` that makes this work, not the `id="video"`. That might be confusing to some people. `id="video"` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Seems like the `src` attribute of the `<source>` element doesn't like to be dynamic.  Try changing your markup to be:

`<source *ngIf="cameraSrc" src="{{cameraSrc}}" type="video/mp4">`

That way the DOM element only gets created when there is indeed a value in `cameraSrc`.

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment because I am too new, sorry.

The reason that interpolation isnt working for you is because its used for data binding , not property binding. The brackets indicate that its a property of the element and not an observable attached to a static property.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem... I settled with using a backing array

```
<span *ngFor="let video of app.videoPlayer.videos">
<img src="{{video.artBig()}}" style="width: 1920px;height: 1080px;top: 0px;left:0px;z-index: -1; position: absolute;"/>

<video preload="auto" crossorigin controls autoplay
   style="width: 1920px;height: 1080px;top: 0px;left:0px;z-index:1; position: absolute;">
  <source src="{{video.url()}}" type="{{video.mimeType()}}">
</video>
</span>
```

Whenever my array is emptied the video component disappears... if my array changes the component gets renew.

Works like a charm, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

in Angular 6, Here is the sample.

```
    <div style="text-align:center">
  <div *ngFor="let item of data" >
    <div class="module hero">
      <a href="javascript: void(0)" (click)="showVideo(item)">
       {{item.name}}
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="selectedItem">
  <video controls autoplay #myVideo>
    <source *ngIf="selectedItem" [src]="selectedItem.url" type="video/mp4" />
    Browser not supported
</video>
</div>
```

And Component code is

```
showVideo(item: any){
    this.selectedItem =null;
    this.selectedItem =item;  
    this.myVideo.nativeElement.src = item.url; 
  }
```