# Rerun a ngSwitch

Tags: html, angular

I have an angular application and in one component I need to display a video. Depending on the user settings, two different videos can be displayed: one in English and another in German. The user can change this setting in this same component. At the moment that's how I have made it:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="lang">
      <video
        id="some-id"
        class="video-js"
        muted
        oncanplay="this.muted=true"
        autoplay
        controls
        controlsList="nodownload"
        disablepictureinpicture
        preload="auto"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      >
        <source *ngSwitchCase="'en'" src="https://linktoEnglishVideo" type="video/mp4" />
        <source *ngSwitchCase="'de'" src="linktoGermanVideo" type="video/mp4" />
        <source *ngSwitchDefault src="https://linktoEnglishVideo" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
</div>
```

The problem is that whenever I change the setting (the `lang` variable) the ngSwitch doesn't re-run and the video is not re-loaded, staying the same no matter what.

Is there a way to force it to rerun and get the right video?

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz demo?>

Comment: Plus what is the scope of `lang` variable?

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngswitch-etssek

Comment: The stackblitz you provided doesn't help: my implementation of the ngSwitch is correct and I can assure you that the `lang` variable does change accordingly when needed. My ngSwitch works fine by using text strings as in your example. The problem in my case is that the ngSwitch is related to videos and the fact that the displayed video doesn't change when switching. I can provide a stackblitz example myself but it could take a while. `lang` is a public variable in the ts class.

Comment: What I will do is: I will use single source tag and assign video url dynamically on language change

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39180415/angular-2-change-videos-src-after-clicking-on-div

Comment: @PrashantPimpale the answer you linked made it work! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing quote marks:

```
<source *ngSwitchCase="'en'" src="https://linktoEnglishVideo" type="video/mp4" />
```

Comment: You're right, I'll correct that, although unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Post your component code.