# Angular 8 - When src changes programatically HTML video element does not change the video

Tags: html, angular, angular8, mp4

I have a MP4 video playing in the background in my web app. However when I update the bindings and change the video source the video stays the same

```
<video autoplay loop>
    <source [src]="videoSrc" type="video/mp4">
</video>
{{videoSrc}}
```

My TS code:

```
this.videoSrc = "video.mp4";
...
interval(10000).subscribe(x => {
  this.videoSrc = "otherVideo.mp4";
});
```

Why aren't the bindings being updated?

Comment: @RameshReddy Yes that's why I put it there

Comment: Can you console.log(this.videoSrc) in interval?

Comment: I guess it works, only when otherVideo.mp4 is fully downloaded. Have you checked it?

Comment: @Beller Yes it shows both sources when using console.log

Comment: @TonyMarko Is there a way to pre load both videos?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39180415/angular-2-change-videos-src-after-clicking-on-div/50914423#50914423

Comment: If answer above not resolve your problem, you could preload your component by display none component and use (load) attribute to show component onload.

Answer (score 20):

You should bind the src property in the video tag instead of binding the source tag.

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline="true" webkit-playsinline="true" [src]="videoSrc" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Check this stakblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hlqbza

Comment: Saved my day ;)

Comment: This worked like a charm. Should be checked as the asnwer !